# Returning by value calls the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
template<class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
   if (vused_ == 0)
   {
      throw "Popping empty stack";
   }
   else
   {
      T result = v_[used_ - 1];
      --vused_;
      return result;
   }
}
```

I didn't understand all of it, or rather I understood none of it, but it was said that this code doesn't work, because it returns by value, I am guessing he was referring to result, and that calls the copy constructor and I have no idea how that's even possible. Can anyone care to explain?

Comment: What was meant when it was said that it "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the code in the question's example, `std::stack<T>::pop` does not return a value.

That's because if the item type needs to be copied, and the copying throws, then you have an operation failure that has changed the state of the object, with no means of re-establishing the original state.

I.e. the return-a-value-`pop` does not offer a **[strong exception guarantee](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html)** (either succeed or no change).

Similarly, throwing a literal string is unconventional to say the least.

So while the code doesn't have any error in itself (modulo possible typing errors such as `vused_` versus `v_` etc.), it's weak on guarantees and so unconventional that it may lead to bugs in exception handling elsewhere.

---

A different viewpoint is that the non-value-returning `pop` of `std::stack` is *impractical*, leading to needlessly verbose client code.

And for using a stack object I prefer to have a value-returning `pop`.

But it's not either/or: a value-returning **convenience method** `popped` can be easily defined in terms of `pop` (state change) and `top` (inspection). This convenience method then has a weaker exception guarantee. But the client code programmer can choose. :-)

---

<del>An improvement within the existing design would be to support movable objects, that is, replace</del>

<del>`return result;`</del>

<del>with</del>

<del>`return move( result );`</del>

<del>helping the compiler a little.</del>

**↑ Correction:**
Actually, the above deleted text has the opposite effect of the intended one, namely, it inhibits RVO (guaranteeing a constructor call). Somehow my thinking got inverted here. But as a rule, don't use `move` on a `return` expression that is just the name of a non-parameter automatic variable, because the default is optimization, and the added `move` can not improve things, but can inhibit an RVO optimization.

Comment: On the other hand, the `move` would inhibit RVO (if it does actually kick in.) Also, does the move really help? I though the plain `return result;` would be enough for a complying compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, right, and yes, right. thanks! i must have had one of those binary inversion moments. :( fixing...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, returning by value formally calls the copy constructor. But that's not a problem at all, because in practice, compilers will typically be able to optimize away the additional copy. This technique is called "Return-Value Optimization".

Comment: I wonder if RVO would work here, `result` being in an `if-else` block.

Comment: @juanchopanza In theory it should; in practice GCC won't do it according to my recent observations.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Don't know about GCC, but VC2013 will apply RVO in this case, but only with the /O2 flag. I just made a compilable and runnable piece of code out of the OP's example and tried for myself. Chances are GCC also requires extra-optimisation flags.

Comment: Interesting. IIRC gcc doesn't change RVO with optimization flags, and I think it is for a good reason: that actually would change the observable behaviour of a well-formed program depending on optimization flags (that is my interpretation.) I ran my own tests, and GCC 4.8.2 doesn't apply RVO, and clang 3.4 does. Both regardless of optimization flags.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You mean if the copy constructor has side effects (which it should not have, of course)? I don't know. In my opinion, it is not so black and white; you may very well consider execution speed to be part of the observable behaviour. Especially if you have multiple threads or other timing-related functionality. So in a certain sense, optimisation always changes the observable behaviour.

Comment: I meant observable behaviour according to the so-called "as-if" rule, which optimizations other than copy elision are suposed to follow. But I agree that it isn't a very well defined concept. Anyway, I prefer *not* to have RVO etc. depend on optimization flags, even if good code shouldn't rely on side-effects of constructor calls.

Answer (score 1):

More than the return statement (which can work if the class is *movable* but not copyable, e.g. you can return `std::unique_ptr`s), the problem is the copy you do here:

> ```
>  T result = v_[used_ - 1];
> ```

To make this copy possible, the type `T` must be copyable (e.g. `T` should have public copy constructor - required by the above statement - and copy assignment `operator=`).

---

As a side note, throwing a string is really bad: you should throw an exception class, e.g.

```
throw std::runtime_error("Popping empty stack.");
```

or just define an *ad hoc* class for this case and throw it, e.g.:

```
class StackUnderflowException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
     StackUnderflowException()
         : std::runtime_error("Popping empty stack.")
     { }
};

....
  throw StackUnderflowException();
```

Comment: The `=` in a declaration introduces an initializer; it doesn't require the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You're right. But I think that a class that does implement a copy constructor but not copy `operator=()` has a bad design (since the user of this class, knowing that it's copyable, would expect also a proper copy `operator=()` overload).

Comment: Yes, that's part of the "rule of three."